# Using the scheduler module on Drupal 6 and Cron

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cron, scheduler

I am wanting to use the scheduler module on Drupal 6 which adds some fields to a node edit page to Publish or Unpublish the node on a specific day and time. The problem is the scheduler is dependent on cron running. The part I'm confused on is how could you possibly schedule a node to publish or unpublish at a specific time unless cron was just constantly running? In other words, if I created a piece of content and scheduled for it to get published two days from now at 8 in the morning, unless cron was running at 8 in the morning, the node would not get published correct? So say for example we only have our cron running twice a day say at 2 in the morning and maybe 2 in the afternoon (I'm just throwing out arbitrary times) and we have our scheduler set to publish our article at 8 in the morning, it technically wouldn't get published until 2 in the afternoon when the second cron activity ran correct? We obviously don't want cron running all the time as it probably wouldn't be good for the site. Am I missing something as far as how this stuff works? OR does anyone have a better solution for allowing nodes to get published and unpublished at set dates and times?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you have [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module in mind to do the task which you have to do. As per the documentation of this module it only publish/unpublished the node when your cron run next to your scheduled timing. This is what has been written over there--

> Scheduled automated publish and unpublish functions occur via the cron
>   system so the actual, real world, publication times will be aligned to
>   when your cron system runs. For example, if you enter a published time
>   of 3:45pm but cron only runs once an hour on the hour then the real
>   publish time will be 4:00pm and not 3:45pm.